# MFC: GUI freezes, but keeps working

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I’ve encountered a problem I can’t solve.

I’m working on a project with MFC in Visual Studio. The problem is, sometimes GUI just stop visibly reacting, but technically it keeps doing the functions it was intended to do. It means, when I press a button, the function OnBnXXXPressed is executing, but the button doesn’t look like it was pressed, as if I’ve pressed on a picture of button, not the button itself. And it’s not just this button — *every other element of GUI* seems to keep working, but doesn’t show that it is working.

Also, in this state dialog windows don’t show up upon their call. If I call AfxMessageBox, the message box won’t show up, and the thread that called this function, **will not** be blocked; AfxMessageBox will basically be skipped.

I have absolutely no idea what can possibly cause that behavior. The question is: *what should be happening in program for it to behave this way? Especially if it’s built with MFC?*

The project consists of 50+ files, and every function responsible for GUI makes changes to the elements it is about. I do not know where the error is, and I ask you, to the very least, **where** should I look for it.

Thank you for attention!

Comment: Have you tried a multi-threading approach? Could be worth investigating if you haven't looked into it yet.

Comment: My guess would be, you are leaking GDI resources. When those are exhausted, controls can't repaint themselves. In Task Manager, turn on "GDI objects" column, see if your process consumes an excessive number of them.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik
This looks reasonable, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was originally provided in the comment section. My code indeed has a GDI resource leak that was provoking this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When a button is clicked, are you doing a bunch of processing, or do you return fast? If you don't return, maybe locking the UI thread. After a user presses on the button, how long is it taking before the OnClick for that finishes running?

If that's it, here's some more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Win7AppQual/preventing-hangs-in-windows-applications

The solution I've generally used for long-running logic on a UI click is to run it a background thread.

Comment: No, that's not it. Every function in family OnBnXXXClicked runs another function in a separate thread. So yes, this is immediate return.